# Reserved keyword in Vimeo (ampersand echo)

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

We noticed an issue when trying to upload a video to Vimeo with the name "Feedback & Echo Chambers". It won't let us.

It won't even save if I change it directly through vimeo.com, without letting me know why.

I narrowed it down to the "& echo" combination. I'm pretty sure it triggers an error on Vimeo side and doesn't allow saving.

I couldn't find any documentation on this, or maybe other character combinations. Anyone have a solution/documentation for this?

For now I am sticking to replacing " & echo" with " and echo".

Comment: As a side note, I decided to submit this question on the Vimeo contact form, but I got the same issue there

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question. This sounds like a question for their support team.